# How to access dataSource outlet class from UITableView?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, delegates, datasource

i have one MYViewController which contains MYTableView, with settings:

1) dataSource outlet is delegated to MYDataSource
2) delegate of MYTableView is set to MYTableView

I have the code in delegate class

```
//MYTableView (delegate is set in storyboard)
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView
{
    //code here

    [(MYDataSource *) self.dataSource loadMoreWithSuccess:^(){
       [self reloadData];
    }];

}
```

but, the dataSource loadMoreWithSuccess cant be accessed, how to call it?

**UPD**

So, after some debugging, i've ended up with following:

```
//MYViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self initTable];
}


-(void) initTable{
    NSLog(@"dataSource: %s", class_getName([_table.dataSource class]));
    // dataSource: MYDataSource
    NSLog(@"delegate: %s", class_getName([_table.delegate class]));
    // delegate: MYTableView
}
```

but in `MYTableView` when i do the following, i get

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView
{   
    NSLog(@"dataSource: %s", class_getName([self.dataSource class]));
    // dataSource: nil
    NSLog(@"delegate: %s", class_getName([self.delegate class]));
    // delegate: nil
}
```

Maybe i didn't notice something important in the Apple Developer Guide?

Comment: Is this method implemented in `MYTableView` or `MYTableViewController`? I guess it would be better to implemented it in  `MYTableViewController` and set the delegate of `MYTableView` to `MYTableViewController`, as you probably don't want to have the table view to be its own delegate.

Comment: In MYTableView.  
Nope, MYTableViewController is only for initial setup, and to change from tableView to cellView (like instagram) and to move between tabs. There is why i have separate dataSource class, in my opinion it will be used in tableView as in cellView. I've put delegate method scrollViewDidScroll in MYTableView because i didn't want to heap up the MYTableViewController.

Comment: You should definetely reconsider setting the delegate to `MYTableViewController`, setting an object as its own delegate doesn't make much sense, the whole point of delegation to let another object take actions on behalf of another object. Maybe you should read the corresponding documentation and then adjust your design: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html

Comment: Amm, i understand this. UPD question